# Screw size for blue old work outlet boxes to hold wings

Tags: electrical, receptacle, screws

I’m not sure of the exact terminology here, but on an old work blue receptacle box you have the two screws that connect to wings that hold the box tight against the wall. I’m trying to install this on a thicker wall so I would like to buy longer screws to replace the default ones that come with the box. Longer screws would give me more room to then easily work with my situation. What type of screw is this that I can reference next time I’m at the big box store?

Comment: Typically the box is screwed tight up against a stud; I can't see how longer screws are a benefit, or how a thicker wall changes anything.

Comment: @Huesmann you’re confusing old work vs new work boxes

Comment: If they are much longer they will just spin, because they won't touch the part of the box that holds them as you tighten them. You might want to look at steel old-work boxes for some different options.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that you're using one of these. I'm not completely sure but I think they're 6-24 threads. Don't go to a big box store. Go to a hardware store, they will have a huge selection of screws of all different sizes. Bring the screw with and you should be able to find what you need.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure they are way more coarse than 6-24. But the advice to go to a good hardware store is sound. Worst case, you can tap the wings for something.